# SwiftUI: How to share Core Data between main app and extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, keyboard

I am making app that stores some data into CoreData and than show it in on the Custom Keyboard. I have already made everything to store that data and created Custom Keyboard Extension, but I am not sure how can I get that data in this extension. I did something with apps group but still now not sure what am I doing wrong.

My DataController:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class DataController: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
    let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: URL.storeURL(for: "group.zo", databaseName: "DataModel"))
    
    override init() {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
        
    }
}




public extension URL {
    
    static func storeURL(for appGroup: String, databaseName: String) -> URL {
        guard let fileContainer = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup) else {
            fatalError("Shared file container could not be created.")
        }

        return fileContainer.appendingPathComponent("\(databaseName).sqlite")
    }
}
```

My KeyboardViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    
    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        let child = UIHostingController(rootView: KeyboardView())
        child.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        child.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        addChild(child)

    }
    
    
}
```

My KeyboardView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var snip: FetchedResults<Snip>
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Your Snips")
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                if snip.isEmpty {
                    Text("error")
                }else{
                    ForEach(snip){ snip in
                        Button {
                            print(snip.content ?? "error")
                        } label: {
                            Text(snip.name ?? "error")
                                .background(Color(snip.color ?? ""))
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    print("siema")
                } label: {
                    Text("test")
                        .background(Color.red)
                }

                Spacer()
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: My CoreData image]

[image: The image of capabilities in main app and target]

Please Help!!!

Comment: This answer might help you understand the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/60178368/321542